# How to display a text in a pop-up screen from an if statement in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox, popup

I would like to display what is in the texbox in the alert message below.

```
 alert("You have selected: " + cbotherstext);

 <input id="cbotherstext" type="text" /></td>
```

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
 alert("You have selected: " + document.getElementById("cbotherstext").value);

 <input id="cbotherstext" type="text" /></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery :

```
 alert("You have selected: " + $("#cbotherstext").val());

 <input id="cbotherstext" type="text" />
```

you also need something that call the function e.g. (with Jquery)

```
<input id="cbotherstext" type="text" />
<a id="example">Example</a>
<script>
$("#example").click(function(){
    alert("You have selected: " + $("#cbotherstext").val());
});
</script>
```

[Example with JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Xs6Be/)

without Jquery

```
   <input type="text" id="cbotherstext" >
   <a onclick="alert_val()"> click me</a>
   <script> function alert_val(){
        alert("You have selected: " + document.getElementById('cbotherstext').value);
   }</script>
```

[Without JQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/c99dG/)

Comment: Thank you for your tremendous work but the one provided by vivek was what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**HTML**

```
 <input id="cbotherstext" type="text" />
```

**Script**

```
$("#cbotherstext").keyup(function(){
    alert("You have selected: " + $("#cbotherstext").val());
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EQB68/